# How can I contain a text node taller than its parent container inside it?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, overflow

I need to be able to contain a text node inside a div, in a way that it does not overflow outside of it, and it doesn't overflow to the parent padding-bottom spacing.

I have tried `white-space`, `overflow`, `text-overflow`, using different display types.

Ideally, I would like the text to be contain inside its parent and use ellipsis to stop the text from overflowing.

Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.image {
  width: 40%;
  height: 170px;
}

.content {
  width: 60%;
  height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div className="item">
  <div className="image"></div>
  <div className="content">
    <span className="title"></span>
    <span className="author"></span>
    <span className="description">text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on the parent of that particular container.

```
  white-space: nowrap;      
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `overflow` css property defines how to deal with content too big to fit in an element.

It can have these values:

- `hidden`: don't show content
- `scroll`: show a scrollbar, allowing you to scroll through the content
- `auto`  : show a scrollbar if needed
- `visible`: show content hanging off the end (default)

The `text-overflow` property can control the behavior of text going off the right end of the element, but not text going out the bottom. This can cause a problem as muti-row text will naturally flow out the bottom. (`white-space: nowrap` will put it all on one line so `text-overflow` it can be used, as suggested by [@AKASH PANDEY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57213150/3990897), but then you only have one line of text.)